# QGIS 3 incorrect rounding with QgsCoordinateFormatter.format()

Tags: qgis, coordinates, debugging, formatting

I use QGIS 3.30.1 to format geographic coordinates.

At some precision values, the formatting result is not what I expected (it is wrong!).

Before writing a bug report, I would like to get a confirmation that I am not the only one who encountered this problem.

Here is the code I am using:

```py
y, x = 61.01896450, 69.08860610
point = QgsPointXY(x, y)
format_flags = QgsCoordinateFormatter.FlagDegreesUseStringSuffix
coords_format = QgsCoordinateFormatter.FormatDegreesMinutesSeconds

for precision in range(7, 11):
    print(QgsCoordinateFormatter.format(point, coords_format, precision, format_flags, Qgis.CoordinateOrder.YX), f'precision = {precision}')
```

Output:

```py
61°1′8,2722000″N 69°5′18,9819600″E precision = 7
61°1′8,27220000″N 69°6′0,00000000″E precision = 8
61°2′0,000000000″N 69°6′0,000000000″E precision = 9
61°1′8,2722000000″N 69°5′18,9819600000″E precision = 10
```

Expected result:

```py
61°1′8,2722000″N 69°5′18,9819600″E precision = 7
61°1′8,27220000″N 69°5′18,98196000″E precision = 8
61°1′8,272200000″N 69°5′18,981960000″E precision = 9
61°1′8,2722000000″N 69°5′18,9819600000″E precision = 10
```

Could you run this code and print the output as an answer here?

Comment: Same result. That's wierd

Comment: This was caused by an integer overflow error. Will be fixed in  3.32.0 / 3.30.3 / 3.28.7 (see https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/52930)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As confirmed by [@KadirŞahbaz](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/29431/kadir-%C5%9Eahbaz) this is a bug. Bug report is [here](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/52927).